# Set Session Cookie

Tags: roku

I am trying to store a session cookie for google analytics

This is the code

```
if valid(m.GATracker.Cookie) then
    print "Cookie:"; m.GATracker.Cookie
else
    m.GATracker.Cookie = 'Random Cookie Number
end if
```

every time I hit the function with this code a new cookie is generated. I thought `m.` was how you stored variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that depends on where this code comes from. You need to paste a bigger segment.

In a global function, `m` is the same as `getGlobalAA()` - but inside a method (that is "a function belonging to a dictionary" in brightscript), `m` actually points to the object itself (i.e. `this` or `self` equivalent).